# Using set on Dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

For my program, I wish to cleanly check whether any elements in a list is a key in a dictionary. So far, I can only think to loop through the list and checking.

However, is there any way to simplify this process? Is there any way to use sets? Through sets, one can check whether two lists have common elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be easy using the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
any(item in dct for item in lst)
```

This is quick, efficient and (IMHO) quite readible.  What could be better?  :-)

---

Of course, this doesn't tell you *which* keys are in the dict.  If you need that, then you're best recourse is to use dictionary view objects:

```
 # python2.7
 dct.viewkeys() & lst  # Returns a set of the overlap

 # python3.x
 dct.keys() & lst  # Same as above, but for py3.x
```

Comment: Because any only returns True or False? So you won't get the common elements from that.

Comment: The original question is "I wish to cleanly check whether any elements in a list is a key in a dictionary."  So this solves that question.

Comment: @user3467349 -- But that's what OP asked for...  "For my program, I wish to cleanly check whether any elements in a list is a key in a dictionary."  OP didn't ask to know _which_ keys are in the dict.  If you want to know which keys, then that's a different story ...

Answer (score 3):

You can test for an intersection between the dictionary's keys and the list items using [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys):

```
if the_dict.keys() & the_list:
    # the_dict has one or more keys found in the_list
```

Demo:

```
>>> the_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> the_list = ['x', 'b', 'y']
>>> if the_dict.keys() & the_list:
...     print('found key in the_list')
...
found key in the_list
>>>
```

Note that in Python 2.x, the method is called [`dict.viewkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems).

Comment: No need for making a `set`; in modern Python you could use `the_dict.keys() & the_list`, or in 2, `the_dict.viewkeys() & the_list`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as efficiency goes, you can't be any more efficient than looping through the list.  I would also argue that looping through the list is already a simple process.

Comment: Thanks, I apologize for stating the question in the wrong way. I probably should have said a cleaner way.